# Finding point on parametric curve such that the tangent is parallel to line

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, parametric

> Let $C$ be a curve defined parametrically as $x=a\cos^3\theta$ and $y=a\sin^3\theta$, where $0\leq
> \theta  \leq\pi/2$. Determine a point $P$ on $C$ such that the tangent at $P $ is parallel to the chord joining the points $(a,0)$ and $(0,a)$.

I have tried to show it by using mean value theorem. This function is continuous and differentiable on $0\leq
\theta  \leq\pi/2$. So by Lagrange mean value theorem, there exists $\theta_1; 0\leq
\theta_1  \leq\pi/2 $ such that $\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)_{ \theta_1}=\frac{y(\pi/2)-y(0)}{a-0}\implies -\tan\theta_1=\frac{a-0}{a-0}=1$. I don't know whether my approach is true or not.

Comment: Please edit your question such that it shows your attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: symmetry => $\frac{\pi}4$

Comment: @Lovsovs  my attempt are given in my updated post

Comment: It helps to know what that curve $C$ looks like. To that end, observe first off that both $x$ and $y$ are positive due to the bounds on $\theta$. Second, note that $(x/a)^{1/3}=\cos\theta$ and $(y/a)^{1/3}=\sin\theta$, so you can find a relation for $y$ in terms of $x$.

Comment: Alternatively, if you look through the list of curves on Wikipedia, you might stumble upon the venerable astroid: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As *karakfa* notes, you could simply see this by symmetry, but you seem to want a more formal approach.

The [parametric derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_derivative#First_derivative) is in this case given as $$\frac{3a\cos \theta \sin^2 \theta}{-3a\cos^2 \theta \sin \theta}=-\tan\theta.$$

Since the line between your two points has slope $-1$, we find $\theta$ s.t. 
$$-\tan\theta=-1 \implies\theta= \frac{\pi}{4}+\pi n, \quad n\in\mathbb{Z},$$

so the solution you are looking for is $$\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}.$$

Comment: @L  thank you for your answer(+1)

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(\dfrac{dy/d \theta}{dx/d \theta}\right)_{\theta= \theta_1}=\dfrac{a-0}{0-a}=-1$$

Answer (score -1):

From the given coordinates, the slope can be calculated to be = -1.

Now as in previous answers I can see that θ=π/4 has been calculated and well shown.

This value can be now be used in x=acos^3θ, where x=a/2.2^(1/2).Similarly, y(whenθ=π/4)= a/2.2^(1/2).

Those will be the answer to the requisite point on C.